# Forbidden minors for "minor closure" of a graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

The Robertson-Seymour theorem (aka graph minor theorem) states that any minor-closed class of graphs has a finite number of forbidden minors. I am interested in the case where the class is given by the "minor closure" of a graph, i.e. the collection of all minors of a graph. I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to find some explicit description of the forbidden minors for this class, but I'm not sure. I can imagine a couple: the empty graph on |V(G)|+1 vertices and adding an edge between non-adjacent vertices. I'm not sure if this is all of them.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forbidden minors $\mathcal{F}$ are empty graph on $V(G)+1$ vertices and all graphs have at most $V(G)$ vertices and are not minor graphs of $G$. We easily have $\mathcal{F}$ is finite, the empty graph forbids all graphs with more than $V(G)$ vertices, the rest forbid all graphs have at most $V(G)$ vertices and are not minor graphs of $G$, and all graphs which are the minors of $G$ don't take any graph in $\mathcal{F}$ as minor graph.

Comment: Is this a minimal description of the forbidden minors?

Comment: We create a poset of all graphs in $\mathcal{F}$ except the empty graph, $F<F'$ if $F$ is minor of $F'$. We take the empty graph and all atom of that poset. To prove this is minimal, we just need to prove every forbidden minors have a big graph (more than $V(G)$ vertices) and have those atom.